# Is phone number required for Authorize.Net payment processing?

Tags: authorize.net

I am creating an application in which i charge payment. For payment, i am using authorize.net. This application can be used all over the world and user needs to give his mobile numner in his own country format. I want to ask is phone number is required for payment processing? If required then ia there any specific format?

Answer (score 0):

The phone number is not a required field for processing a payment through Authorize.Net.

It is also not required when creating a payment profile. You can confirm it by [testing it in their API reference](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles-create-customer-payment-profile).